# How to convert System.DateTime To System.TimeSpan explicitly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to convert a Date Time time to Time Span format time explicitly . As i have to change time from DateTime to Time span in my reminder app

Comment: Extremely unclear. Some sample of conversions (like "1930-03-13T01:33Z should be converted into 23 minutes because XXXXXX") would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeSpan` in general denotes the Time difference between two `DateTime`. Hence you need to establish a baseline date for the difference.

You can try using

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

but the above will use a baseline time of `12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001`

---

Trying to answer just by guessing your problem

Let say you have a event in your remain app created for `15th June 2014`

```
DateTime eventDate = new DateTime(2014, 6, 6);

// now to show the timespan you can use
TimeSpan ts = eventDate - DateTime.Now.Date;

// time left to event
Console.WriteLine("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes", ts.TotalDays, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes);
```

Comment: It's a reminder app so he has a target datetime.

Comment: @slugster - his question seems partially incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

That operation doesn't make sense, so you can't do it. Any cast attempts will fail.

This makes sense when you think about it, what does "May 21, 2014 4:00 PM" mean as a time span? A time span is something like "4 hours 10 minutes, 5 seconds" which is clearly not a date or time.

If you subtract two `DateTime` objects you will get a `TimeSpan`, but other than that it is impossible.